# Como não distorcer o layout ao abrir o teclado?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu tenho um linear layout com um formulário. sempre que o teclado é aberto ele distorce o meu layout deixando meus Buttons pela metade, tem alguma forma de manter meu layout intacto quando o teclado é aberto??
Algum comando que trave meu layout atras do teclado??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fala Edu,

Tenta colocar essa linha dentro do seu método onCreate:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Isso vai fazer com que o layout se ajuste sem distorcer, quando você abrir o teclado.

Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado era o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

A opção que você está procurando é a [adjustPan](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft). No Manifest, coloque na entrada correspondente à sua Activity:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    ...
>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uso isso para o layout se ajustar com o teclado aberto, talvez possa te ajudar!

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```